# Powershell Do Until variable contains string twice

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run tracert command 2 times by using a do loop. I am doing this simply by counting the number of times "Trace complete." shows. So in the script below, I want the loop to run until the variable contains "Trace complete."  2 times.  But obviously its not working.

```
do {
         $2+= tracert $ip 

   } until ( $2.Contains("Trace complete.") -ge 2) 

 #(  $2 | select-string "Trace complete").length -eq 2
```

I also tried the select string method but both don't result in loop ending until Trace Complete has appeared twice. Any help please?

**Edit 1:**

I would also like to store the output of tracert in a variable so i can view it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tracert` command returns an **array of strings** thus the `Contains()` function will not work here.

Here is a solution where I increase the `$count` variable which is initialized with `0` by **1** every time the `tracert` command contains the string *Trace complete* by using a regex. if the *joined* string doesn't contain the term, I increase the variable by **0**.

Finally, the *until* condition will stop when the `$count` variable is greater equal 2.

```
$count = 0
$output = do { 
    $output = tracert 127.0.0.1
    if (($output -join '' -match 'Trace complete\.')) {
        $output # outputs the tracert result
        $count++
    }

} until ( $count -ge 2) 

$output
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer. Sorry i think I did not clarify what I was asking for  but I also want to see the output of tracert. Can that be added to your script?

Comment: I changed the code. It now outputs your desired result.

Comment: Once the script is finished executing, it shows 2 results of tracert which is correct but when I check the $output variable, i only see the tracert results once instead of twice? Basically I am trying to run the tracert twice and mail the output.

Comment: I changed the code again. This time the output from the `do` loop gets captured and stored to the outer `$output` variable which you can reuse...

Comment: This is EXACTLY what i was looking for. Thank you so much!!! :)